# many/much fireworks?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I  found that "firework" is countable  noun  but sometimes  it may be uncountable.  So,  now I'm wondering how to use this word.

would you say:

I've never seen so many fireworks

or

I've never seen so much fireworks

??

Comment: Only "many" is possible here, where "fireworks" is being used a count noun.

Answer (score 1):

Well fireworks can have two different meanings:

> I've never seen so *many* fireworks

You're watching a pyrotechnic display.

> I've never seen so *much* fireworks.

You're observing outbursts of anger.

Comment: Even if using "fireworks" figuratively, I would still say "many" ... although I'd probably say "a lot of fireworks" instead.  I'm not sure how I feel about "much fireworks" -- I'd probably interpret it as a *doge* meme.